# Launch Screen .XIB with full screen image view

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, asset-catalog

I have created `LaunchScreen` for my iOS app project which has an image view which is anchored to top, left, bottom and right edges of root view with 0 space.

Q1.What should be the resolution of the image for supporting all screen sizes for iPhone and iPad in landscape or portrait?

Q2.Should I be again providing images of different resolutions for different screen sizes and orientations for iPhone and iPad like `LaunchImage` asset?

[image: Launch Screen XIb]

Comment: do you realize there is also such thing as contentMode plays the role? it affects the way how image fits the imageview frame. it may be cropped or stretched or displayed in real size.

Comment: I am using content mode 'Aspect Fill' which works well for all devices. Again the question would be what should be the size of the image so that it doesn't pixelate?

Answer (score 1):

**Q1.What should be the resolution of the image for supporting all screen sizes for iPhone and iPad in landscape or portrait?

Regarding to @heximal** 

You can set "Scale to fill" mode for your image view and provide any image size (size of you xib, for example). 
**Q2.Should I be again providing images of different resolutions for different screen sizes and orientations for iPhone and iPad like LaunchImage asset?**
Create new image set in assets and provide just 3 images for your launch screen -@1x @2x @3x

Comment: Q1.What do you mean by 'any size' ? Currently the image resolution is 1024*768 and with 'Scale to fill' mode it looks odd. Q2.What would be size of @1x image?

Answer (score 0):

Refer:

[image]

Or visit below link for all image sizes:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW2